# Test Explorer's test results don't match with those from debugging

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, testing, visual-studio-2012

I have written some simple tests in Visual Studio 2012 using [gtest](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/) and every one of them passes as I would like to but as they pass in the command line one of them fail, namely the one that expects a file to be loaded from some location. Code:

```
TEST(configTest, paramsTest) { 
    Config cfg;
    ASSERT_TRUE(cfg.loadConfigFile("config100.txt"));
    EXPECT_EQ (100, cfg.getBoardHeight());
    EXPECT_EQ (100, cfg.getBoardWidth());
    EXPECT_EQ (100, cfg.getGoldNumber());
    EXPECT_EQ (100, cfg.getPlatinumNumber());
    EXPECT_EQ (100, cfg.getWallsNumber());
}
```

When I debug the test I get 100 in every field of `cfg` (+ the test passes when I launch the application normally from VS) but when I use Visual Studio's Test Explorer then I have this :

I assume this is a problem with working directory but I know Project's working directory and I put the configs there, so I don't know where should I search for Test Explorer's working dir.

Can I adjust this somewhere ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should copy this file to your $(OutDir) using a post build event [using msbuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)